# How to target a sibling element in a WPF trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress, datatrigger

I want to have a button that displays a dropdown menu when clicked.

So far, I've this:

```
    <dx:SimpleButton  Padding="1" Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      Command="{Binding CreateItem}" >
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="True">
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="16" Height="16" Source="../Resources/Add.png" Margin="10" />
            <dx:SimpleButton Name="DropDownButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Padding="1" Margin="0,1,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
                <dx:SimpleButton.Content>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="../Resources/customDropDown.png"  />
                </dx:SimpleButton.Content>
                <dx:SimpleButton.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="DropDownMenu" PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding PasteItem}" Header="Paste" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </dx:SimpleButton.ContextMenu>
                <dx:SimpleButton.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger SourceName="DropDownButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </dx:SimpleButton.Triggers>
            </dx:SimpleButton>
            <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Slot.Name}" /> 
        </DockPanel>
    </dx:SimpleButton>
```

But when I click on the button, I've this error:

```
'DropDownMenu' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'DevExpress.Xpf.Core.SimpleButton'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You realise if you right click a button then it's context menu will open? Being usual windows behaviour the user is more likely to expect it to work that way as well.

Comment: @Andy I do yes. The goal is more to have a dropdown control with a specific look & feel

Comment: Did you try this for a built-in `Button`? It works.

Comment: @mm8 Yeah I saw it worked with the base button :(